# TSQL: Insert Into Table with if condition

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, insert, union

I've made a small simple table here:

```
declare @live bit = 1
declare @temp table(id int, title varchar(30))

insert into @temp (id, title)
select 1, 'myTitle1'
union select 2, 'myTitle2'
union select 3, 'myTitle3'

select * from @temp
```

Output:

```
id  title
-------------
1   myTitle1
2   myTitle2
3   myTitle3
```

Now I want the title attribute to be dependent from @live

I'll show it in pseudo-code:

```
declare @live bit = 1
declare @temp table(id int, title varchar(30))

insert into @temp (id, title)
select 1, IF (@live == 1) THEN 'myTitle1_live' ELSE 'myTitle1'
union select 2, IF (@live == 1) THEN 'myTitle2_live' ELSE 'myTitle2'
union select 3, IF (@live == 1) THEN 'myTitle3_live' ELSE 'myTitle3'

select * from @temp
```

How would this look in sql syntax?

Comment: You are probably looking for [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a conditional expression:

```
select id,
       (case when @live = 1 then concat(title, '_live') else title end)
from @temp;
```

If the data is already in the table, then you would use `update`:

```
update t
    set @title = concat(title, '_live')
    from @temp t
    where @live = 1;
```